# microsoft script center: don't have permission to upload sample when adding contribution

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, technet

Following error shown when trying to add my first contribution in Microsoft script center. I am looking to add script to azure automation runbook gallery.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is not a code issue but a resource access issue on a site the Stack Overflow does not control, as per your error message.

You should reach directly to the scriptcener / powershellgallery owners/managers to address why you are having this issue.

There are many blog posts on how to do this type of submissions, generally speaking.

[Publishing Scripts to the PowerShell Gallery](http://www.brianbunke.com/blog/2017/01/09/publishing-scripts)

[How To Upload a Module to the PowerShell Gallery](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/08/04/upload-a-module-to-the-powershell-gallery.aspx)